# Why no overloaded constructor implementations in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, constructor, overloading

In TypeScript it's only possible to overload the constructor type signatures, but not the Implementation. Is there and reason behind this? Overloading constructors like in Java are really useful I think. For example a definition for vectors could be the end cordinates, or start and endpoint or two vectors and so on. 
The current approach in TypeScript is very chaotic. So why doesn't typescript have it?

Comment: You'll have to ask the language designers, everyone else can only speculate. See [a similar case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292416).

Comment: TypeScript is not a language; it's a pre-processor, transpiled into JS. It merely checks and emits. It cannot override basic language restrictions such as not having multiple versions of functions with the same name. This limitation applies to all methods, not just constructors. If you want to program in Java, then program in Java.

Comment: @torazaburo typescript is more than a preprocessor. Look at the compiler's code, it's less a preprocessor and more a language that emits Javascript (which is the 'bytecode' of the javascript VM. If there was anything lower level, it could emit that). It's implemented like many other programming languages.

Comment: A matter of semantics. The fact remains that by virtue of emitting JS, it cannot arbitrarily change the core functionality of the language.

Comment: @torazaburo Javascript is turing complete, typescript could simulate anything. That they *choose* not to is a whole different thing.

Comment: For instance, there was no way in JS to implement WeakMaps or proxies in JS until they were added to the core.

Comment: @torazaburo Let's not mix our apples and oranges here. Of course TS can't change the nature of the underlying language, but they could emulate any kind of higher level functionality, e.g. proper overloads. But they don't want to, as it's an explicit goal to keep TS close to JS.

Comment: Actually, in this specific case, it would break interop with JS and not actually be possible. It's true that due to Turing completeness, they could put any higher level construct in the language, but in specific cases like this one, the code wouldn't be accessible for interop.

Comment: @SimonMeskens Not necessarily, TS could as a start insert logic in the constructor/merged function that checks the number of arguments and then executes specific logic accordingly. Then we at least have slightly better overloading based on argument count. And I'm sure we even could have some type checking if we properly give the compiler relevant custom type guards. I'm not saying it's always easy and performant, but nothing is impossible.

Comment: @Alex Ah yes, that would work. Sounds like a bad idea for several reasons, that might also be fixed, but sure, hadn't considered that. Cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10696) and the outcom is: It would be technically doable, but would break the design goals.
Thanks for everyone participating in the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a reason for it, and the reason is that javascript does not support using the same name for a method or a member.

Consider the following typescript:

```
class MyClass {
    myMethod() {}
    myMethod(str: string) {}
}
```

The compiled version is:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () { };
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function (str) { };
    return MyClass;
}());
```

As you can see, the 2nd implementation of `myMethod` is replacing the first implementation.
Because of that you can only overload the signatures and then you need to provide a single implementation which satisfies all of the declared signatures.

Comment: wouldn't 2 constructors result in 2 MyClass functions? And since javascript does not support polymorphism 2nd would overwrite the first one making it impossible to have 2 constructors.

Comment: @toskv Right, a 2 ctor would theoretically end up as a 2nd `MyClass` function which will override the first .

Comment: @NitzanTomer that's why it's currently not working, but the compiler is changeable and just because it currently compiles as you mentioned doesn't mean it could be changed to compile to different js-code implementing something with a single "real" constructor and helper constructors in parallel which represent the overloaded typescript constructors.

Comment: @Phosphoros True, that can be added to the language, in addition to a lot of others things, but then typescript as a language will diverge too far from javascript which is against the philosophy of the language.